# Find all the possible permutations using Ruby and recursion

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've been trying to solve a simple quiz question to find all the possible permutation of a string using Ruby and recursion.

I have the following Ruby code:

```
def permutation(string)
  return [string] if string.size < 2

  chr    = string.chars.first
  perms  = permutation(string[1..-1])

  result = []

  for perm in perms
    for i in (0..perm.size)
      result << (perm[0..i] + chr + perm[i..-1])
    end
  end

  return result  
end
```

Whenever I try to test the code with **puts permutation("abc")** I get the following output:

```
cacbc
cbabc
cbcac
cbca
cacb
cbab
cba
```

Theoretically speaking it's supposed to be a very simple and straightforward problem, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Most probably it's something with the ranges of the loops. And I know that Ruby Array class has instance method *permutation* to do that but I'm trying to solve it for practising.

Please note that the complexity is O(N!) for the current implementation. Is there anyway to enhance the performance further?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To see what the difficulty may be, let's try it with an even simpler example:

```
string = "ab"
```

Your desired result is `["ab", "ba"]`.  Let's see what you get:

```
string.size #=> 2
```

so we don't return when

```
return [string] if string.size < 2
  #=> return ["ab"] if "ab".size < 2
```

is executed.

Next we calculate:

```
chr = string.chars.first #=> "a"
```

Notice that a more direct way of making this calculation is as follows:

```
chr = string[0]  #=> "a"
```

or, better, using [String#chr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-chr),

```
chr = string.chr #=> "a"
```

The latter illustrates why `chr` is not the best choice for the variable name.

Next

```
perms = permutation(string[1..-1])
  #=> = permutation("b")
```

I will now indent the return values to emphasize that we are calling `permutation` a second time. `permuation`'s argument is:

```
  string #=> "b"
```

Now when we execute:

```
  return [string] if string.size < 2
  #=> return ["b"] if "b".size < 2
```

we return `["b"]`, so (back to original call to `permutation`):

```
perms = ["b"]
```

to go with `chr => "a"`, calculated earlier. Next:

```
result = []

for perm in perms
  for i in (0..perm.size)
    result << (perm[0..i] + chr + perm[i..-1])
  end
end
```

As `perms` contains only the single element `"b"`, the two `for` loops simplify to:

```
for i in (0.."b".size)
  result << ("b"[0..i] + "a" + "b"[i..-1])
end
```

which is:

```
for i in (0..1)
  result << ("b"[0..i] + "a" + "b"[i..-1])
end
```

Notice that `"b"[0..0]`, `"b"[0..1]` and `"b"[0..-1]` all equal `"b"[0]`, which is just `"b"`, and `"b"[1..-1] #=> ''`. Therefore, when `i => 0`, we execute:

```
result << ("b"[0..0] + "a" + "b"[0..-1])
  #=> result << ("b" + "a" + "b")
  #=> result << "bab"
```

and when `i => 1`:

```
result << ("b"[0..1] + "a" + "b"[1..-1])
  #=> result << ("b" + "a" + "")
  #=> result << "ba"
```

so:

```
result => ["bab" + "ba"]
```

which clearly is not what you want.

What you need to do is is change the double `for` loops to:

```
for perm in perms
  result << chr + perm
  for i in (1..perm.size-1)
    result << (perm[0..i-1] + chr + perm[i..-1])
  end
  result << perm + chr
end
```

which could be written more compactly by employing the method [String#insert](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-insert):

```
for perm in perms
  for i in (0..perm.size)
    result << perm.dup.insert(i,chr)
  end
end
```

which you would normally see written like this:

```
perms.each_with_object([]) do |perm, result|
  (0..perm.size).each { |i| result << perm.dup.insert(i,chr) }
end
```

Notice that we have to `.dup` the string before sending `insert`, as `insert` modifies the string.

Doing it like this, you don't need `result = []`.  Neither do you need `return result`, as `parms.each_with_object` returns `result` and if there is no `return` statement, the method returns the last quantity calculated.  Also, you don't need the temporary variable `perms` (or `ch`, if desired).

Putting this altogether, we have:

```
def permutation(string)
  return [string] if string.size < 2
  ch = string[0]
  permutation(string[1..-1]).each_with_object([]) do |perm, result|
    (0..perm.size).each { |i| result << perm.dup.insert(i,ch) }
  end
end
```

Let's try it:

```
permutation("ab")
  #=> ["ab", "ba"]
permutation("abc")
  #=> ["abc", "bac", "bca", "acb", "cab", "cba"]
permutation("abcd")
  #=> ["abcd", "bacd", "bcad", "bcda", "acbd", "cabd",
  #    "cbad", "cbda", "acdb", "cadb", "cdab", "cdba",
  #    "abdc", "badc", "bdac", "bdca", "adbc", "dabc",
  #    "dbac", "dbca", "adcb", "dacb", "dcab", "dcba"]
```

Eki, which one are you in the picture?

Comment: Wow man, more than helpful. It's just what I was trying to debug :) Many thanks bro. And I'm the guy in the middle :) My GF and my best friend are with me :) Cheers mate

Comment: StackOverFlow is a beautiful place just because there are beautiful people like you. An answer like a poem... Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Array#permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-permutation):

```
def permutation(string)
  string.permutation(string.size).to_a
end

permutation('abc'.chars)
# => [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "c", "b"], ["b", "a", "c"], ["b", "c", "a"],
#     ["c", "a", "b"], ["c", "b", "a"]]
```

**UPDATE** Without usign `Array#permutation`:

```
def permutation(string)
  return [''] if string.empty?

  chrs = string.chars
  (0...string.size).flat_map { |i|
    chr, rest = string[i], string[0...i] + string[i+1..-1]
    permutation(rest).map { |sub|
      chr + sub
    }
  }
end

permutation('abc')
# => ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help. But as I mentioned I'm aware of Array#permutation, I mentioned that with the post. I'm just trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.